# some files are missing! using Math.net numerics 2.4.0

Tags: c#, winforms, teamcity, numerics

I'm using Math.Net numerics ver 2.4.0 in my C# project, winform and after running the project and doing some parts it says:

> **find a source:ManagedLinearAlgebraProvider.Double
>   original location: c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4ecde2945c804d6\src\Numerics\Algorithms\LinearAlgebra\ManagedLinearAlgebraProvider.Double.**

and open a window to locate it when I press cancel the program continuous But entries of my matrices changes to NAN.

This is not the only file it wants, each time it needs a different file. What should I do?

I thought package is miss installed so I removed it and install it again but it didn't work.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW5mr.jpg),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCn2x.jpg)
and these are pictures of error.(Click on Blue 1 & 2)

Comment: Please include relevant code parts.

Comment: This is likely to be a problem with your Team City setup. Does the the project builds OK locally?

Comment: i think the pic is not readble ... is it?!
what should I do please help!

Comment: @ChrisF yes it builds and compute 4 or 5 times (it is a iterative procedure) but after that become NAN

Comment: Your question is not clear.  We are unable to read the error message display within Visual Studio.  Verify the configuration of your `Team City` setup.  For instance when did this stop working?  What "parts" exactly were ran?

Comment: @Ramhound there is loop in my program in this loop some calculations are done on matrices... after 4-5 times that this loop ran, that error appears. I found that by running program line by line, if I run it normally it never ends and no error either.

Comment: @bunNyBug - Post the loop.  The picture is not readable.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to post new image but because someone have down voted this question, it says:
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
You need at least 10 reputation to post images.

any way by clicking on blue 2 at the end you can see the image in a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens when there is a logical problem with matrix operation , for example if a matrix is not a square matrix but in code you try to inverse it, this error appears.

my problem was in math of my program... and fixed finally.